# Connect my Laravel to a external Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can i connect my laravel to an extneral Database?

Example: I have a laravel on my local machine which is running on xammp. And i want it to connect to a cloud Server database.

Comment: Hi & welcome to the SO. Please read this first [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you must change `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
` in your `.env` file

Answer (score 2):

Open the `.env` file and edit it. Just set up correct external DB credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1         // set external DB_Host 
DB_PORT=3306             // Your Database Port
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Your Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

`DB_USERNAME` should be set to **root** if you do not have a default username in the installation time

If no password is set on the database, just clear it `DB_PASSWORD`

After `.env` edit, must be clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 2):

In **.env** file you can set `DB_CONNECTION` with your database name and applicable databases are given in `/config/database.php` which are (SQLite, MySQL, pgSQL, SQLSRV) after that just type your **username**, **password**, and **database name** and you can use that database with port number.

Answer (score 2):

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=laravel
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=
```

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql_second' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

**If You are use Eloquent Model**

add this line

```
protected $connection = "mysql_second";
```

**If You are using Database Facades**

```
DB::connection('mysql_second')->table('table_name')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In .env(This is in root folder) file change below credentials accordingly with external DB connection:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and in config/database.php change the below  credentials if trying to connect with external MySQL otherwise there are more options for others or please mention from which DB you want to connect with

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: First, just change
HOST( your Host IP), DATABASE( Name Of database), USERNAME( Database User Name) and PASSWORD( password for this user name) in both the files and try.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but, I'm using REST API and every time I use my GET as curl it's redirecting to logins in my laravel.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Enable MYSQL Remote**

First, you need to read your hosting docs to get your server data and instructions to enable mysql remote for your local IP by whitelisting your IP or if you want to allow access to anyone you can use wildcard `%`

in my case HostGator: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database-remotely,

**2. Change `.env` configuration**

then fill `.env` file with the provided data by your hosting provider.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 //replace with your external server IP
DB_PORT=3306 // check open port for mysql usually is 3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel // replace with the name of your external database
DB_USERNAME=root //replace with the username associated with database
DB_PASSWORD= //put your username password
```