# Try to connect localhost laravel project to another database from another server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to use database from another server to my local-host laravel project. I configure .env file and config\database.php file like below. I am able to access my local database but unable to access outside database. I get error: **"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ExecUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `value_list`)** "

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=180.48.10.222
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=nsu
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=ExeUs
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=******


'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '180.48.10.222'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect my Laravel to a external Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897647/connect-my-laravel-to-a-external-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause: You forgot to change the host, port to host another.

Please update the code same below:

```
'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a second connection you will also have to change the host and url configs for the second connection.
At the moment the problem is that the `url` and `host` point to the localhost `DB_HOST`and `DB_PORT` .env variables.

They should point to `DB_HOST_SECOND` and `DB_PORT_SECOND`, respectively.